# Как вернуть массив и использовать его для другой функции?

Tags: c#, методы, return

У меня есть метод Formula(int[] arr), которому необходимо передать в параметры возвращаемый массив из метода Input(), каким образом это можно реализовать?

```
using System;

namespace Laba10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Какую программу запустим (1 - шаг и промежуток, 2 - вывод, 3 - сортировка №1, 4 - сортировка №2, 5 - сортировка №3, 6 - статистика, 7 - выход)?: ");
                char answer = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (answer)
                {
                    case '1':
                        Program.Input();
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        Program.Formula(Input());
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        static int[] Input()
        {
            Console.Write("Введите точку начала: ");
            int begin = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Укажите шаг: ");
            int step = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Введите интервал: ");
            int interval = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            int[] arr = new int[] { begin, step, interval };

            Program.Main();
            return arr;

        }

        static void Formula(int[] arr)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите значение а: ");
            double a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Введите значение b: ");
            double b = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double y = 0, x;

            if (arr[0] < arr[2] && arr[1] > 0)
            {
                while (arr[0] <= arr[2])
                {
                    x = arr[0];

                    if (Math.Sqrt(x - b) != 0)
                    {
                        y = (a + b * x * Math.Tan(x - b)) / (Math.Sqrt(x - b));
                        Console.Write($"{x}\t {Math.Round(y, 2)}");
                    }

                    arr[0] += arr[1];
                }
            }
            else if (arr[0] > arr[2] && arr[1] > 0)
            {
                while (arr[0] >= arr[2])
                {
                    x = arr[0];

                    if (Math.Sqrt(x - b) != 0)
                    {
                        y = (a + b * x * Math.Tan(x - b)) / (Math.Sqrt(x - b));
                        Console.Write($"{x}\t {Math.Round(y, 2)}");
                    }
                    arr[0] -= arr[1];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Введены некорректные данные");
            }
            Program.Main();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы в ``case '2':`` как раз это и делаете

Comment: И когда обращаюсь ко второму кэйсу, у меня вновь запрашивается метод Input()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно просто сохранить данные в переменную.

```cs
static void Main()
{
    int[] array = null;
    bool exit = false;
    while (!exit)
    {
        Console.Write("Какую программу запустим (1 - шаг и промежуток, 2 - вывод, 3 - сортировка №1, 4 - сортировка №2, 5 - сортировка №3, 6 - статистика, 7 - выход)?: ");
        if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int answer))
            Console.WriteLine("Некорректный ввод");

        switch (answer)
        {
            case 1:
                array = Input();
                break;
            case 2:
                if (array != null)
                    Formula(array);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Нет данных");
                break;
            case 7:
                exit = true;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

И уберите вызов `Program.Main` из методов `Input` и `Formula`.

Comment: Разве при возвращении в мэйн любого из методов, массив не будет преобразован в null?

Comment: @JeffreyWillis кем преобразован? зачем преобразован? `Main` - обычный статический метод, он ничем технически не отличается от любого другого статического метода. В C# нет никакой скрытой магии, никто не будет портить ваши данные в вашем коде кроме вас самих.

Comment: @aepot обратите внимание, что в коде у автора происходит в методах `Input()` и `Formula()`. Там вызывается метод `Main`

Comment: @AndreiKhotko не ожидал такой подставы, спасибо! Дополнил ответ.

Comment: @JeffreyWillis уберите вызов `Program.Main` из методов `Input` и `Formula`, вообще, совсем, удалите эти 2 строчки, и все заработает.

Comment: @aepot, задача состоит ещё в том, что бы пользователь имел возможность вернуться к выбору пункта, потому мне и необходимы вызовы метода Main();

Comment: @JeffreyWillis У вас и так произойдет возврат из метода в метод Main, сам по себе. Вы попробуйте. После завершения работы любого метода происходит возврат в метод, из которого был вызов, и продолжение выполнения кода.

Comment: @aepot, возможно я и ошибаюсь, но программа обрывается после выполнения первого же пункта, да и к тому же, метод выполнился и дальнейших инструкций у него нет, с чего бы ему возвращаться в мэйн?

Comment: @JeffreyWillis 1) удаляете `Program.Main();` из методов `Input` и `Formula` 2) берете код из ответа и вставляете вместо своего кода в `Main` 3) всё работает. 4) `с чего бы ему возвращаться в мэйн` с того что это так работает. Когда метод завершается, происходит возврат в вызывающий метод ровно в ту строчку, с которой был вызов.